# set type of an image captured using iPhone camera

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

If we capture a picture using iPhone camera, image will be saved in JPEG format by default.

I would like to save the image captured in other formats like PNG. Is it possible?

Is it possible to do this from code when we invoke iPhone camera from our application, can we set image type it has to be saved after capturing picture? I mean to open Camera and set the type before capturing picture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will help you to save image in png type

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
  didFinishPickingImage : (UIImage *)image
             editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
NSError *error;

NSString  *pngPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/%@.png",@"photoname"]];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:NO];


NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@", [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error]);

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: We can save in PNG or JPEG using above PNG or JPEG Representations.. But all i want to know is, first time save should be in PNG format.. I am not interested in conversions..

Comment: @jithen, in the above code there is no conversion of image format, it directly saves the image in png format

Comment: when the user captures the image in iphone camera, the `didFinishPickingImage` will be called, the image will be directly saved in png format, see the code

Answer (score 6):

```
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

// png image data

NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

// jpeg image data

NSData *jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, compressionQuality);  // compressionQuality = 0.0 to 1.0 --> 0 means maximum compression and 1 means minimum compression
```

Once you get NSData, you can save this data to specific file. For more details go through this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Check updated ans. For JPEG data, compression ratio requires. For more details go through the apple reference link attached in ans.

Comment: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage gives already saved image.. I need capturing image from camera with PNG format type

Comment: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage - It will provide you image in object format UIImage, which is not yet stored anywhere. To save that image you will require to writeToFile. Before doing that you can convert your UIImage to NSData using given two methods. Those methods convert your UIImage object to specific image type (PNG/Jpeg) data.

Comment: Once you got the NSData format, save your file using writeToFile method. Provide fileName+extension as per your selected conversion (PNG/Jpeg)

Answer (score 1):

You could use something similar to this in your method to save the captured object as a PNG:

```
// Create paths to output images
NSString  *thePngPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Example.png"];
NSString  *theJpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Example.jpg"];

// Write a UIImage to JPEG with minimum compression (best quality)
// The value 'image' must be a UIImage object
// The value '1.0' represents image compression quality as value from 0.0 to 1.0
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:theJpgPath atomically:YES];

// Write image to PNG
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:thePngPath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: If we have an image, then we can convert to PNG or JPEG format using the above code... But my doubt is how to capture an image with PNG format from camera key directly... We can convert after capturing.. But i want image directly in PNG format without any conversions...

Answer (score 1):

Use this code,

```
NSData* pngdata = UIImagePNGRepresentation (image); //PNG wrap 
UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithData:pngdata];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: Whats the format type of "image" here.... It will be JPEG for sure if u captured that from camera.. what i want to know is, can we capture image in PNG format using camera? If yes, how to do that