# What accuracy should I expect from basic opencv ortho-rectification algorithms?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

So, I'm taking over the work on an ortho-rectification algorithm that is intended to produce "accurate" results. I'm running into trouble trying to increase the accuracy and could use a little help.

Here is the basic approach.

1. Extract a calibration pattern from an image that was taken from a mobile phone.
2. Rectify the image based on a calibration pattern in the image
3. Scale the image to get the real world size of the scene around the pattern.

The calibration pattern is held against a flat surface, like a wall, counter, table, floor and the user takes a picture. With that picture, we want to measure artifacts on the same surface as the calibration pattern. We have tried this with calibration patterns ranging from the size of a credit card to a sheet of paper (8.5" x 11")

Here is an example [input picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XttRx.jpg)

With this resulting [output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5cqQ.jpg)

Right now our measurements are usually within 1-2% of what we expect. This is sufficient for small areas (less than 25cm away from the calibration pattern. However, we'd like the algorithm to scale so that we can accurately measure a 2x2 meter area. However, at that size, the current error is too much (2-4 cm).

Here is the algorithm we are following.

```
// convert original image to grayscale and perform morphological dilation to reduce false matches when finding circle grid
Mat imgGray;
cvtColor(imgOriginal, imgGray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

// find calibration pattern in original image
Size patternSize(4, 11);
vector <Point2f> circleCenters_OriginalImage;
if (!findCirclesGrid(imgGray, patternSize, circleCenters_OriginalImage, CALIB_CB_ASYMMETRIC_GRID))
{
    return false;
}

Point2f inputQuad[4];
inputQuad[0] = Point2f(circleCenters_OriginalImage[0].x, circleCenters_OriginalImage[0].y);
inputQuad[1] = Point2f(circleCenters_OriginalImage[3].x, circleCenters_OriginalImage[3].y);
inputQuad[2] = Point2f(circleCenters_OriginalImage[43].x, circleCenters_OriginalImage[43].y);
inputQuad[3] = Point2f(circleCenters_OriginalImage[40].x, circleCenters_OriginalImage[40].y);

// create model points for calibration pattern
vector <Point2f> circleCenters_ObjectSpace = GeneratePatternPointsInObjectSpace(circleCenters_OriginalImage[0], Distance(circleCenters_OriginalImage[0], circleCenters_OriginalImage[1]) / 2.0f, ioData.marker_up);

Point2f outputQuad[4];
outputQuad[0] = Point2f(circleCenters_ObjectSpace[0].x, circleCenters_ObjectSpace[0].y);
outputQuad[1] = Point2f(circleCenters_ObjectSpace[3].x, circleCenters_ObjectSpace[3].y);
outputQuad[2] = Point2f(circleCenters_ObjectSpace[43].x, circleCenters_ObjectSpace[43].y);
outputQuad[3] = Point2f(circleCenters_ObjectSpace[40].x, circleCenters_ObjectSpace[40].y);

Mat lambda(2,4,CV_32FC1);
lambda = Mat::zeros(imgOriginal.rows, imgOriginal.cols, imgOriginal.type());
lambda = getPerspectiveTransform(inputQuad, outputQuad);

warpPerspective(imgOriginal, imgOrthorectified, lambda, imgOrthorectified.size());
...
```

**My Questions:** 
Is it reasonable to shoot for error < 0.25%? Is there a different algorithm that would yield more accurate results? What are the most valuable sources of error to identify and resolve?

As I've worked on this, I've also looked at removing pincushion / barrel distortions, and trying homographies to find the perspective transform. The best approaches I have found so far remain in the 1-2% error.

Any suggestions of where to go next would be really helpful

Comment: What are the pixel dimensions of the target in the picture you are starting with? (The physical size doesn't matter) If the calibration target is 400pix square then one pixel error exceeds your 0.25% objective. Your sample image is jpeg, this introduces noise - is this the original? I'd have thought that to stand the remotest chance of achieving that sort of accuracy the target will have to be completely flat, in the picture it appears to be not completely flat.

Comment: How accurately do you know the size of the target? You will have to measure it to considerably better than 0.25% accuracy - if you say at worst 0.1% that's to within 0.01inches for a 10" target - you anywhere near that accurate?

Comment: Pixel dimensions are 484 x 342 (outermost rows of circles). So, I see how that will limit accuracy. Thanks.  We used precision calipers to measure the pattern on the target image. So, we do have 0.01 inches "accuracy". Well, that too is limited by the accuracy of the calipers... You are right the printed paper is not perfectly flat. If the approach is good enough, then we will print it on plastic cards so it will stay flatter.

Comment: And yes, it is jpeg. We are using mobile phone cameras, but only from a browser so don't think we have access to other formats right now. I guess from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358527/set-type-of-an-image-captured-using-iphone-camera), it would be possible to save as png if we built an app for it. Would png help? Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: As long as it isn't just a png saved from a jpeg then it might help reduce the noise in the image. Anything that reduces the noise/increases the precision of your image of the target should help. However it is difficult to imagine how you can improve on the basic noise content built in to your data by its resolution - if your image is already at or above a 0.25% floor then you are very very unlikely to be able to get overall projection accuracy anywhere near that. IMO you need much higher resolution/precision of the images to stand any chance of getting better projection estimates.

Comment: Can you adapt the feature extraction to get sub-pixel coordinates for the target centres?? (That might allow you to increase precision) Can you make the target full-frame? Do you need the array of targets? (if the target is truly planar then four corner points, or dots along the boundary, might be just as good). Would making the target points cross-hairs allow more precise location?

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, @barny. I can look at feature extracting in sub-pixel coordinates. I suspect it is doing that because it is using OpenCV and most of our information is in floats, but I'll look into it. Can't make the target full-frame because the application is to measure the sizes of objects around the target  The array of targets is useful for OpenCV to find the card. will look at smaller array sizes, or perhaps a checkerboard pattern which has the precise intersection points.